# Deleting a table cell while cell's textfield is in focus crashes the app

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView that can have as many table cells as user needs.
Each cell contains UITextField that its text value is inserted to an array on EditingDidEnd.
Cells can be deleted.

My app will crash when user tries to delete a cell while the cell's textfield is active (in focus).

I need to either disallow delete while the cell's textfield is in focus or disable save on EditingDidEnd when delete is pressed.

How can I achieve this with the following code?

```
@IBAction func stepTextFieldEditingDidEnd(sender: UITextField) {

    let pointInTable = sender.convertPoint(sender.bounds.origin, toView: self.stepTableView)
    let textFieldIndexPath = self.stepTableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(pointInTable)

    steps[(textFieldIndexPath?.row)!] = sender.text!
}
```

[image]

Comment: What error do you receive in the console? It could just be a matter of resigning the first responder before delete

Comment: Error is on `steps[..] = sender.text!` and I think it's about sender.text! value is nil because it's deleted. I think Delete fires first and then EditingDidEnd. Console doesn't say this explicitly other than `Thread 1: EXE_BAD_INSTRUCTION ...`

Comment: Does it not give you an error such as Array index out of range or anything like that in the console? Presumably it's an index issue as there is one more array item than there is table cells. Is it possible to try removing the index of the array when delete is pressed?

Comment: It doesn't give me index out of range error. I can remove the index of the array when textfield is not in focus. When the textfield has focus and try to remove the cell, I get the runtime error and won't proceed.